# Alternative/third-party superzoom for Nikon?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, nikon, zoom, third-party, superzoom

I have a Nikon 18-200 VR which I think is great. I often use the 200mm part of it so I'm thinking of an even more extreme superzoom, but I'm not familiar with other lenses than Nikon, but I have been thinking about Tamron 18-270.

Has anyone experience with this lens? I have not seen any good reviews of it or comparisons with the Nikon 18-200? How do they compare?

Also, are there any other alternatives? I saw a superzoom in a magazine some weeks ago that went from 16-xxxmm and that could also be interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the Tamron 18-270 for my Canon, and very happy with it.

Comment: Will give it a try. I think this is the only obvious choice. A 70-200 is not a superzoom.

Comment: If you are thinking about going Full Frame in the future, there's also a 28-300, which a colleague of mine had for his Canon 5D and was very happy with it too.

Answer (score 2):

There's a new Nikon 28-300mm f/3.5-5.6 VR lens you might consider for about $1000. [Ken Rockwell loves it](http://www.kenrockwell.com/nikon/28-300mm.htm).

Comment: Thanks. Saw it. Only problem is the need for a d700 ontop of that :)

Comment: ken rockwell? really

Answer (score 1):

The 16-xx you're thinking of may be the Tokina 16.5-135 which was announced a year or two ago; available at [B&H for $450](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/652825-REG/Tokina_ATXAF635DXN_16_5_135mm_f_3_5_5_6_AT_X_DX.html). It's a nice focal range in general but not if you're wanting more than 200mm.

Note that the 18-200's internal focus design means that when focusing close, it's considerably shorter than 200mm. So it could be that a real 200mm would meet your needs.

You might also consider a zoom which is longer but less super, such as the 70-300 VR or the AF-D version which is not VR but is very inexpensive ($150).

Answer (score 1):

The full frame for Tamron 28-300 is actually getting a pretty good review (check [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00066EK40)). Here is the dpreview lens review for Tamron 18-270 (ASP-C): [DPREVIEW](http://www.dpreview.com/lensreviews/tamron_18-270_3p5-6p3_vc_n15/) (not bad for a super zoom)

Answer (score 1):

I was in a similar situation, and I decided to get a used 70-200mm f/2.8 and the Nikon TC-17E teleconverter. It is a pretty pricey solution, but the lens is great!

See my somewhat related question [here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/439/70-200mm-teleconverter-or-a-longer-zoom-lens)